# Matching subset of DOM nodes based on previous disconnected HTML element

Tags: ruby, csv, nokogiri, mechanize

A page I am trying to scrape into a CSV database/Ruby array lists 470 total records of uneven sized groups, each group preceded by a date (22 unique dates total).

I am not sure how to do it since groups aren't organized into any HTML tables, nor any hierarchy in the DOM where a "parent" could lead to each group's date, only a dry list of `<div class="line">` visible record divs, occasionally preceded by only a `<span class="date">Thursday, May 24, 2012</span>` holding the date that applies only to the next X records until a new date is printed.

In `irb` it correctly shows:

```
$page = $agent.get(pageurl) # gets page with Mechanize
doc = $page.parser # returns Nokogiri::HTML 

(records = doc.search('html body div#wrapper div#innerwrapper div#content div.line')).size 
=> 470
(dates = doc.search('html body div#wrapper div#innerwrapper div#content span.date')).size 
=> 22
```

Show the first date for example:

```
doc.search('html body div#wrapper div#innerwrapper div#content span.date')[0].text
=> "Wednesday, May 23, 2012"
```

My goal is to append the correct date as a field to each of the 470 **records** doc.search found above, before saving into a CSV file.

Can Nokogiri (or Mechanize) help me retrieve these records in groups based on their position in the DOM, i.e. immediately following `dates[N].text` but before the next `<span class="date">`?

I could iterate N from 0 to 21 appending to a master array/CSV object for all 470 records, but for each group, adding the appropriate `date` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can simplify your search a bit. Since content is an `id`, and it by definition uniquely identifies that particular `div`, you don't need any of the preceding path information.

```
records = doc.search('div#content div.line')
```

From each record, you can pull the date using xpath's `preceding-sibling` axis. Altogether:

```
doc.search('div#content div.line').each do |record|
  date = record.xpath('preceding-sibling::span[@class="date"][1]').text
  #append to CSV
end
```

The XPath says: find the preceding spans at the same level (`preceding-sibling::span`) that have a class of "date" (`[@class="date"]`), and take the first such one (`[1]`) to ensure you get the nearest date span).

Comment: Yep thanks! Currently I am futzing with the exact xpath since it is coming up blank for date. Looking for possible uncle/parent hops etc. Maybe I'll post a snip of the HTML if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Interestingly, in an earlier revision I had the date as an "uncle" node in my sample html. I used `../preceding-sibling::span` to get to it. (`..` means parent)

Comment: The version that gave me trouble was prior to your edit. This works for me: `records[0].xpath('preceding-sibling::span[@class="date"][1]').text` Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is another good time to use traverse:

```
doc.traverse do |node|
  @date = node.text if 'span' == node.name && 'date' == node[:class]
  puts [@date, node.text].join(', ') if 'div' == node.name && 'line' == node[:class]
end
```

Comment: Also great! I see what's going on there. This `traverse` will be useful--reminds me what I was madly getting ready to do with just raw text processors like `sed` and `awk`, outside of any xml/xsltproc or nokogiri aids.